# deSolve package can parameters include a matrix?

Tags: r, parameters, matrix

I'm trying to code an SEIR model that is age-stratified; that is, in my differential equations I have a parameter for mass action that is the sum of beta*(proportion infected)*(number susceptible) over 20 age classes.  The transmission coefficient (beta) is calculated from a contact matrix. The contact matrix has 20 columns and rows which represent the age classes (rows=person i, columns=person j), and contains the probability of contact between two people in any age classes.  I designed it and read it into R. My problem is I don't know how (or if) I can use a matrix inside my parameters with deSolve.  This code below I wrote doesn't work, I believe because of the matrix / I get this error:

```
Error in beta * S : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

Before I fool with it too much, I'd like to know if it is possible to use a matrix like this as a parameter for this model.

```
mat <-as.matrix(read.csv("H:/IBS 796R/contactmatrix.csv", header=F))

times <- seq(0,20,by=1/52)
parameters <- c(mu=0,v=1/75,N=1,p=0,delta=2.4,beta=mat*0.04,sigma=1/8,gamma=1/15)
xstart <- c(S=0.06,E=0,I=0.001,R=0)

SEIR0 <- function(t,x,parameters){
    S=x[1]
    E=x[2]
    I=x[3]
    R=x[4]
    with(as.list(parameters), {
        dS=v*S -beta*S*I/N -delta*S
        dE=beta*S*1/N -E*(sigma+delta)
        dI=sigma*E -I*(gamma+delta)
        dR=gamma*I-delta*R
        res=c(dS,dE,dI,dR)
        list(res)
    })
}

out <- as.data.frame(lsoda(xstart,times,SEIR0,parameters))
```

Also, if I print the parameters, this is what beta looks like:

```
$beta.V1
 [1] 4e-04 4e-04 4e-04 4e-04 4e-04 4e-04 4e-04 4e-04 4e-04 4e-04 4e-04
[12] 4e-04 4e-04 8e-03 8e-03 8e-03 8e-03 8e-03 8e-03 8e-03

$beta.V2
 [1] 4e-04 4e-04 4e-04 4e-04 4e-04 4e-04 4e-04 4e-04 4e-04 4e-04 4e-04
[12] 4e-04 4e-04 8e-03 8e-03 8e-03 8e-03 8e-03 8e-03 8e-03
```

....through $beta.V20. So I think it's creating 20 vectors, each with 20 arguments...I think each is a row of the original matrix 'mat' multiplied by the constant 0.04? However, when I multiply mat*0.04 outside "parameters" I get the expected matrix. I'm struggling a bit with how to realize these equations using deSolve and would appreciate any advice on whether it's possible. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error occurs in this line :

```
dS=v*S -beta*S*I/N -delta*S
```

`non-numeric argument to binary operator` means you try to multiply a function for example by a numeric. You can reproduce it by `I*1`

```
Error in I * 1 : non-numeric argument to binary operator`
```

Here, R can' find beta , and  beta is interpreted as the Special Functions of Mathematics, so the error.
You need to define parameters as

```
# a list 
list(mu=0,v=1/75,N=1,p=0,delta=2.4,beta=mat*0.04,sigma=1/8,gamma=1/15)
```

and

```
 ## you get a vector mu,N,p,delta,beta1,bet2,...  
c(mu=0,v=1/75,N=1,p=0,delta=2.4,beta=mat*0.04,sigma=1/8,gamma=1/15)
```

I think you can even rewrite your function as:

```
SEIR0 <- function(t,x,parameters){
  with(as.list(c(parameters, x)), {
    dS = v*S -beta*S*I/N -delta*S    ## matrix
    dE = beta*S*1/N -E*(sigma+delta) ## matrix
    dI = sigma*E -I*(gamma+delta)
    dR = gamma*I-delta*R
    res = c(dS,dE,dI,dR)
    list(res)                        ## different of the structure of xstart
  })
}
```

This will correct the problem above but the ODE will not work because the number of derivatives returned by SEIR0  must be equal to the length of the initial conditions `xstart` vector(4 here).

I suggest for example :

```
  res <- c(dS=mean(dS),dE=mean(dE),dI=dI,dR=dR)
  list(res)
```