# Problems with ODE solver in R

Tags: r, variables, parameters, ode

so let's say that we have an arbitrary system of ODEs in R, which we want to solve, for example a SIR model

```
  dS <- -beta * I * S
  dI <-  beta * I * S - gamma * I
  dR <-  gamma * I
```

I want beta and gamma to have time varying parameters, for example

```
 beta_vector <- seq(0.05, 1, by=0.05)
 gamma_vector <- seq(0.05, 1, by=0.05)
```

User @Ben Bolker gave me the advice to use beta <- beta_vector[ceiling(time)] inside the gradient function

```
    sir_1 <- function(beta, gamma, S0, I0, R0, times) {
    require(deSolve) # for the "ode" function
   
     # the differential equations:
     sir_equations <- function(time, variables, parameters) {
         beta <- beta_vector[ceiling(time)]
         gamma <- gamma_vector[ceiling(time)]
         with(as.list(c(variables, parameters)), {
             dS <- -beta * I * S
             dI <-  beta * I * S - gamma * I
             dR <-  gamma * I
             return(list(c(dS, dI, dR)))
           })
       }
     
       # the parameters values:
       parameters_values <- c(beta=beta, gamma = gamma)
       
         # the initial values of variables:
         initial_values <- c(S = S0, I = I0, R = R0)
         
           # solving
           out <- ode(initial_values, times, sir_equations, parameters_values)
           
             # returning the output:
             as.data.frame(out)
        }


sir_1(beta = beta, gamma = gamma, S0 = 99999, I0 = 1, R0 = 0, times = seq(0, 19))
```

When I execute it it gives me the following error

```
Error in checkFunc(Func2, times, y, rho) : 
The number of derivatives returned by func() (1) must equal the length of the initial 
 conditions vector (3)
```

The problem must lay somewhere here:

```
parameters_values <- c(beta=beta, gamma = gamma)
```

I have tried to change the paramters_values to a Matrix with two  rows (beta in the first, gamma in the second) or two columns, it did not work. What do I have to do in order to make this work?

Comment: I can't reproduce your error. In fact, I can run `sir_1(beta = 1, gamma = 1, S0 = 99999, I0 = 1, R0 = 0, times = seq(0, 19))` successfully.

Comment: @Peace Wang: I don't want gamma and beta to be fixed with 1 (or any other value) I want in  sir_1(beta = beta, gamma = gamma, S0 = 99999, I0 = 1, R0 = 0, times = seq(0, 19)) the beta and gamma to be the above defined vectors

Comment: Two points: 1. I can't reproduce your error even with your code. 2. Where  you define the gamma and beta? It shouldn't be defined within `sir_equations` or `sir_1` function.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help me, that is really weird because I've run it again, and get the same error:  This part I have defined outside the function beta_vector <- seq(0.05, 1, by=0.05)
 gamma_vector <- seq(0.05, 1, by=0.05). Inside the sir_equations I have beta <- beta_vector[ceiling(time)]
         gamma <- gamma_vector[ceiling(time)]

Comment: I guess  the `beta` and `gamma` appeared here `dS <- -beta * I * S,
dI <-  beta * I * S - gamma * I, dR <-  gamma * I` should be a value instead of vector.

Comment: yes exactly, do you know how I could change that dS/dI/dR to be able to receive vectors?

Comment: Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15331394/desolve-package-can-parameters-include-a-matrix?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code had several issues, one is that time starts with zero while ceiling needs to start with one, and there was also some confusion with parameter names. In the following, I show one (of several) possible ways that uses `approxfun`s instead of `ceiling`. This is more robust, even if `ceiling` has also some advantages. The parameters are then functions that are passed to`ode`as a list. An even simpler approach would be to use global variables.

One additional consideration is whether the time dependent `gamma` and `beta` should be linearly interpolated or stepwise. The `approxfun` function allows both, below I use linear interpolation.

```r
require(deSolve) # for the "ode" function

beta_vector <- seq(0.05, 1, by=0.05)
gamma_vector <- seq(0.05, 1, by=0.05)

sir_1 <- function(f_beta, f_gamma, S0, I0, R0, times) {

  # the differential equations
  sir_equations <- function(time, variables, parameters) {
    beta  <- f_beta(time)
    gamma <- f_gamma(time)
    with(as.list(variables), {
      dS <- -beta * I * S
      dI <-  beta * I * S - gamma * I
      dR <-  gamma * I
      # include beta and gamma as auxiliary variables for debugging
      return(list(c(dS, dI, dR), beta=beta, gamma=gamma))
    })
  }
  
  # time dependent parameter functions
  parameters_values <- list(
    f_beta  = f_beta,
    f_gamma = f_gamma
  )
  
  # the initial values of variables
  initial_values <- c(S = S0, I = I0, R = R0)
  
  # solving
  # return the deSolve object as is, not a data.frame to ake plotting easier
  out <- ode(initial_values, times, sir_equations, parameters)
}

times <- seq(0, 19)

# approxfun is a function that returns a function
f_gamma <- approxfun(x=times, y=seq(0.05, 1, by=0.05), rule=2)
f_beta <- approxfun(x=times, y=seq(0.05, 1, by=0.05), rule=2)

# check how the approxfun functions work
f_beta(5)

out <- sir_1(f_beta=f_beta, f_gamma=f_gamma, S0 = 99999, I0 = 1, R0 = 0, times = times)

# plot method of class "deSolve", plots states and auxilliary variables
plot(out)
```

Comment: PERFECT. Thank you so so much